# Looking for a cross-platform language

Tags: programming-languages

Lately, I've been looking for a good, lightweight language with these traits:

- Cross-platform, at least for Windows and Linux.
- Lightweight, fast, really portable and quick to setup/get running.
- Most importantly, it has to have most of the stuff baked into it. I don't want to fiddle around                                with libraries, download anything extra and such.

I've looked into countless options already. Ruby, Tcl, Wren, Lua for example, but I fell like most of them fall short on certain areas. I know a lot of Python already and I love it, but I fell like it falls short in some of my wishes too.

Is there any language corresponding to the features I said and if not, what's the closest match?
Sorry, if I am being a bit too picky.

Comment: I think recommmendation questions are off topic for this site... That said, have you checked out .NET Core? Also, your desire for it "to have everything baked in" might be a bit unrealistic. However modern languages have package managers which alllow you to download and use external libraries easily. Add to that easy packaging into a final executable and that's probably the best you'll get. Coincidentally, .NET Core does that...

Comment: Also check out Rust. I have no experience with it, but it's a modern language which is highly loved by programmers, so I suspect it should be good. Also C/C++ _can_ be lightweight and portable, but you'll need to be careful to keep it so. And, depending on what you want to do, you might need external libraries.

Comment: I rarely post here, so yes, how I set the topics and such are probably way off. Yes, I know .NET core as I've recently been learning C#. For some reason, I haven't thought it as a viable option. I need to look into it more considering my purposes.

Comment: Obviously, I've heard about Rust and apparently it's really hard, so I haven't even bothered to look into it more. Same goes for C/C++ as I still consider myself not experienced enough for those.

Comment: I've always been fascinated by C++ so a few years back I decided to try and read a book about it. What I soon realized is that it's not so much difficult as it is just messed up. When they introduced new concepts in the language/standard library that were sorely needed, they tried to make them "backwards compatible" so that old timers would have an easier time working with the new things, since they would have the same "look and feel" as the hacks they've used so far. This has resulted in something (in my opinion) horrible, which makes the whole language a lot more difficult than it has to be.